# Controlling the executions of CPP Preprocessor

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am using standard CPP to preprocess any C/CPP file.
I am using the below command for preprocessing:

```
cpp -idirafter <path_to_header_files> -imacros <sourcefile> <source_file> > <destination_file>
```

The above command is replacing all the macros with its corresponding implementations defined in header files.

If I want some specific MACROS containing a particular string (eg, ASSERT) should not replace by cpp preprocessor. ie, if  any macro defined by the name of TC_ASSERT_EQ or TC_ASSERT_NEQ defined in some header files should not replace by preprocessor.

Is there any ways I can control this?

Comment: Make sure that the macros are not defined? Which might be hard if they are defined in a header file you don't control.

Comment: First replace them with some unused names and then replace them back?

Comment: What if you create a "compile time define" and pass it to compiler with -D but not to pre-compiler. Lets say `gcc -DPERMIT_ASSERTS`. Then with this one you can mask out all the macro definitions you want to protect, both in headers and source files using `#if defined` as test.

Comment: Use a search and replace before you run - such that ASSERT becomes ASSERT__donotsub or the like - and then replace back once your done (and if you have semi long list you could use a regex for that). Would that be a workable solution for you ?

Comment: Did You try `#undef`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used #pragma poison TC_ASSERT_EQ statements to pass the line without preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use predefined macros to work around this. You can pass different defines to cpp and gcc/g++ using -D parameters

For example your assertion header can look like `my_assert.h:`

```
#ifndef __my_assert_h__
#define __my_assert_h__

#if defined  ASSERT_DEBUG
 #define my_assert(expr) my_assert(expr) /* please dont touch my assertions */
#else
 #define my_assert(expr) ((void)0U)      /* Your assertion macro here */
#endif /* ASSERT_xxx */

#endif /* #ifndef __my_assert_h__ */
```

And your source files can be as before. For example `test.c:`

```
#include "my_assert.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void foo (int p) {
   my_assert(p==1);
   puts("Tralala\n");
}

int main (void) {
   foo(1);
   return 0;
}
```

With the above trick you can run
`cpp -DASSERT_DEBUG test.c`

While the compilation still works as before.
`gcc test.c`

Comment: Sounds good, but I don't  have control to change either header file or .c file.. I can only use them as it is to do preprocessing.  @hoo2

Comment: The source files are not affected. You can make local copies (or a repository branch for ex) and create an assert header wrapper. Or something similar. With the information we have, I can not tell you exactly. But the logic suggest that you have to change something.